# Japanese Star Trek Fonts

Tags: fonts, font-identification, japanese

I've been looking into Japanese Star Trek media, and I was hoping to find 3 fonts they used.

This first one is likely based off of the Galaxy Font (also known as Star Trek Film BT). There are 2 other fonts I need, but apparently I'm only allowed a single link.

[image: Star Trek 2 Japanese logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Japanese site http://www.usskyushu.com/trekfont.html which has a home-brewed *katakana* Star Trek font.

It is very limited (only contains *katakana*), but it does work. In that font your picture looks like this

[image]

(The font doesn't contain numbers nor *kanji* or *hiragana*, so I had to write all of it with the available glyphs in *katakana*.)

The site said that even though there are many Latin Star Trek fonts out there, there aren't any for Japanese (except for the one apparently used in the movies). That's why he tried to reproduce it himself. (Maybe this means that there is not a more complete font out there...)

Comment: This helps a bunch! A shame there aren't any more fonts out there. Do you think you could search for the 2009 Japanese Movie font for me just in case? I'd post a link but I'm very new to Stack Exchange.