# Japanese Title Font

Tags: logo, japanese, tv-series

I was hoping to locate the font used for this open title from the original broadcast of Star Trek in Japan. I'd guess it was in use anywhere from the 1960's to 1980's, but I'd wager on the former.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Uchu Daisakusen logo]

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85811/36660